# Setting a value of a jQuery cookie based on a C# value

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, cookies

Ladies and Gentlemen,

I seem to have stumbled upon an issue, to which I can't found a solution.
I'm using the jQuery cookie plugin for the application.

Short version of the scenario:

"I'm setting two cookies which will be used later on in the code.
Lets call them value1 and value2.

Whenever the user clicks a button, the value1 value is set to 0 and the value2 value should be set to a DateTime, equal to the MyDateTime property form the codebehind.

Attempt #1

```
function btnConfirm_Clicked(source)
     {
     // Cookie setter
     $.cookie("activityPadAlertDateOld", 0);
     $.cookie("activityPadAlertDate", <%= this.MyDateTime %>);
     }
```

Attempt #2

```
function btnConfirm_Clicked(source)
     {
     var testVar = <%= this.MyDateTime %>;
     // Cookie setter
     $.cookie("activityPadAlertDateOld", 0);
     $.cookie("activityPadAlertDate", <%= this.MyDateTime %>);
     }
```

Seems pretty straightforward, does it not ? The issue is, the function completely ignores the c# value I've provided (I added the semicolon on var testVar = <%= this.MyDateTime %> in order to check something - it displays a syntax error, thus I am assuming that the code treats it as an empty space).

To be fair, I think I've checked almost every cookie-related question I think there is, nothing seemed to work. My javascript knowledge is rather limited (I'm learning it), therefore I might have made some foolish mistake somewhere.

PS.: Yes, I did try removing the semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<%= this.MyDateTime %>` will print the value as it is, without quotes.

Try

`"<%= this.MyDateTime %>"`

PS: You could have checked the HTML/JS generated.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Finally, some progress. Had my DateTime value returned as 13%2F10%2F2013%2017%3A47%3A11, so now the only thing that remains is figuring out what on earth do 2017%3A47%3A11 represent. Thanks a lot matey :)

Comment: The weird thing is, though, whenever I attempt to give it DateTime.Today value, for example, it gets me an "Index was outside the bounds of the array." exception

Comment: That exception does not look even remotelly related with `DateTime.Today`. I think it deserves a separate question.